# Bridged interfaces do not have internet access

Tags: networking, arch-linux, qemu, bridge

I'm trying to run a QEMU VM but it doesn't have an internet access, only access to the host and a Docker network.

What I did:

1. Created a bridge with: `brctl addbr virbr0`;
2. Turned it on: `ip link set up dev virbr0`;
3. Assigned an IP: `ip addr add 192.168.66.1/24`;
4. Updated the QEMU config: `echo "allow virbr0" >> /etc/qemu/bridge.conf`;
5. Run the virt-install:

   ```
   virt-install \
     --name centos67 \
     --memory 1024 \
     --vcpus=1,maxvcpus=2 \
     --cpu host \
     --cdrom $HOME/Downloads/CentOS-6.7-x86_64-minimal.iso \
     --disk size=4,format=raw \
     --network bridge=virbr0
   ```

Then I started a rescue image and configured a network:

> IP: 192.168.66.2/24
>
> Gateway: 192.168.66.1

That's all, at this moment I only have an access to the host and the Docker network, but no internet (so ping 8.8.8.8 failed).

Here is the output of some hosts utilities which could be helpful to help me to solve this issue:

```
$ brctl showstp virbr0
virbr0
 bridge id              8000.fef8a25ccef1
 designated root        8000.fef8a25ccef1
 root port                 0                    path cost                  0
 max age                  19.99                 bridge max age            19.99
 hello time                1.99                 bridge hello time          1.99
 forward delay            14.99                 bridge forward delay      14.99
 ageing time             299.99
 hello timer               0.00                 tcn timer                  0.00
 topology change timer     0.00                 gc timer                 167.03
 flags


tap0 (1)
 port id                8001                    state                forwarding
 designated root        8000.fef8a25ccef1       path cost                100
 designated bridge      8000.fef8a25ccef1       message age timer          0.00
 designated port        8001                    forward delay timer       12.95
 designated cost           0                    hold timer                 0.00
 flags

$ ip route
default via 192.168.232.2 dev envmw  proto static  metric 100
192.168.5.0/24 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.5.1
192.168.66.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.66.1
192.168.232.0/24 dev envmw  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.232.100  metric 100
212.25.224.10 via 192.168.232.2 dev envmw  proto static  metric 100

$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             255.255.255.255

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             a01.dev.lo  tcp dpt:pxc-splr-ft
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             a01.dev.lo  tcp dpt:pxc-spvr-ft
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             a01.dev.lo  tcp dpt:newoak
```

Looks like I missed some configuration step but I don't know which one. I tried to google a solution but didn't find any.

Comment: Please take a look at the [libvirt Networking Wiki page](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking) to get an idea at least of what's required; maybe it'll help you backtrack your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it works I had to enable NAT.

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o envmw -j MASQUERADE
$ iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o envmw -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added a physical interface (`envmw`) to your bridge. You also need to set that interface to promiscuous mode without an IP address:

```
brctl addif virbr0 envmw
ip addr add 0/0 dev envmw
ip addr del 192.168.66.1/24 dev envmw
ip link set envmw promisc on
```

Running these commands from a remote session is a bad idea, because it's changing the interface configuration. This in turn will disconnect any remote traffic - including the remote session.

Comment: No, it doesn't fork, it even brakes hosts network connection at all.

Comment: @rtkh I don't understand "_it doesn't fork_".

Comment: it doesn't work =) btw it looks like i just forgot to configure NAT on my host machine

Answer (score 0):

I use this command to fix the issue:

```bash
sudo nft flush ruleset
```